how to handle large data request
I am getting 15k-20k of json data from frontend and at backend (flask) i am processing data by iterating over each item and checking if record allready there or not if not i am adding that item in DB session object. At last i am commiting changes to DB.
Problem in current implementation is

it's taking 20-25 min.
it's failing frequently with error code 502 and 503.

sample of data (single)
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'abc',
  related: [{id:2, name:'def', access: true}]
}

how can i optimise it. what can i do to handle load so that api will not fail.

Does id match the primary key of the record in the database?

@snakecharmerb
no, in db id is autoincreament has no relation with this record.
we are checking existance on basis of name, related_name and it's access

How do you iterate over the json? Hopefully you are parsing it to a dict and then iterating over it? If so it shouldn't take that long. Otherwise where exactly is the bottleneck? By saying 15-20k json data, do you mean kbs/mbs or lines of data?

@BcK
15-20k mean , items in list, each item is unique and contains another children of atleast array of 4.means total iteration is 20 * 4  =80 K.
there is no need to parse in dict.

There's no need to json.loads? Well, how do you iterate over it then? Line by line?

yes, one by one, now i am looking to use some threading concept to make it faster.

Just parse the json and load it into a dict with json.loads and then iterate over each item. You are wasting your time if you are literally iterating over a huge string separated by newlines. You don't need threading. Don't make your problems more complicated.
